# set tabindex and class to FCK editor

Tags: php, javascript, editor, ckeditor, fckeditor

i have problem to set **tabindex** to **FCK editor** . i am using following php code for fck editor

```
require_once("".$abspath."fckeditor/fckeditor.php");
    $oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor("shippinginfo") ;
    $oFCKeditor->BasePath = "../fckeditor/" ;
    $oFCKeditor -> Height = '300';
    $oFCKeditor -> Width = '900';
    $oFCKeditor->Value = stripslashes(str_replace("\\","",$product_shippinginfo));
    $oFCKeditor->Create() ;
```

and i also like to **class**  to fck editor

any one have the idea

Comment: read this [article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/fckeditor-custom-styles/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by textarea replacing method we can set `tabindex`. so it works thanks !

```
 <textarea name="product_long_tescription" id="product_long_tescription"  tabindex="4"  class="fillbymaster" >init value</textarea>


window.onload = function()
{
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'product_long_tescription' ) ;
oFCKeditor.BasePath = "../fckeditor/" ;
oFCKeditor.Height = "300" ; 
oFCKeditor.Width = "900";
oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

by the way i google and find below solution... try this

```
open file: fckeditor.js

find there a string:


return '<iframe id="' + this.InstanceName + '___Frame" src="' + sLink + '" width="' + this.Width + '" height="' + this.Height + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" tabindex=4></iframe>' ;
```

to add Class

```
Find these lines in FCKedotor's confing file, fckconfig,js

// This will be applied to the body element of the editor
FCKConfig.BodyId = '' ;
FCKConfig.BodyClass = '' ;
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833789/add-class-or-id-to-fckeditors-editable-iframe-body)